# Is there an advantage to using a for-loop over a while-loop in file reading?

Tags: java, performance, loops, file, cumulative-sum

While doing some practice problems with file reading, I came upon a question. The nature of this question required me to read the file and potentially stop partway through. After coming up with one solution, I thought of another and wondered which would be more efficient-(file is of type java.util.Scanner here)-

**While-Loop**

```
// create default values
byte loops = 0, sum= 0;
// loop while there is data and a non-negative sum 
while(file.hasNextInt() && sum >= 0)
{
    sum += file.nextInt();
    loops++;
}
```

**For-Loop**

```
// create default values
byte loops = 0, sum = 0; 
// loop while there is data and a non-negative sum 
for(;file.hasNextInt() && sum >= 0;
    sum += file.nextInt(), loops++);
```

#EDIT for depth#
Goal: print the negative sum and number of loops that it took to reach or state that it had a positive-sum.

Comment: They're equally efficient.

Comment: Side note: either you have a bug or your comment is wrong. the comment is `// loop while there is data and a negative sum` but the loop condition means it will loop while there is data and a ***non*** negative sum

Comment: AHA good catch! You are spot-on, thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are virtually the same. You'll find a lot of things can be done in different ways, sometimes extremely different ways. When that's the case, I tend to lean towards the code that's easier for the humans who have to deal with it: me and my coworkers. Personally, I find the while loop is much more readable. With the while you're not leaving out parts of the structure or using them in a unique fashion like you are with the for loop.

My only efficiency concern is that you're using `byte` as the type for your variables. I know absolutely nothing about the size of the file or the numbers that are in it so it seems very possible that you could overflow or underflow a byte. Especially in Java where a byte is signed.

Comment: Would there be an ideal datatype? I see that **int** is used very commonly. I am trying to make a practice of not wasting space, though hindsight is very strong and -128 is only a few entries away!

Comment: @KemperLee That's called "premature optimization".  The time you spend thinking at this level is worth MUCH more than a couple of bytes of storage unless you're dealing with billions of objects.  At current DDR4 memory prices, 1 byte costs $0.00000003. And one byte of disk costs $0.00000000003.  Write the code using standard data types and worry about performance ONLY when you can prove there's a problem.

Comment: @jim true, but IMHO even more important is the dollar cost of code that's hard to read; developers time and bugs are expensive. Code that's easier to read and conventional but somewhat less efficient (with same time complexity) wins for me.

Comment: Thank you for such clear responses. This depth is getting me even more excited to be involved in the real-world application of these concepts. My professor says anything over 30 lines (excluding comments and white-space) can likely be broken down, but five lines should be left alone!

Comment: @Bohemian Agree completely.  Maintenance cost (or worse, accumulated tech debt) is the most expensive part of software dev.

Comment: @KemperLee comments? What comments? This may shock your professor, but best practice is the code have *no* comments in the implementation. The idea being that the code should be well written enough to not need comments. For example, if you feel like a few lines needs a comment, refactor those lines into a new method and make the name of the method be so descriptive that a comment is not necessary. Similar reasoning goes for class and variable names. Classes and methods should not have comments either, except when describing peculiarities, limitations or unexpected side effects etc.

Comment: @KemperLee since we’re talking about a loop counter here, I’m assuming that it is a local variable. In this case, using `byte` is counter-productive. The calculation will be done in the `int` value space anyway. When you use `byte`, an *additional* instruction will be inserted to convert the result back to the `byte` value space and achieve a potential overflow at 128. With `int`, `loops++` compiles to a single `iinc …,1` instruction. With `byte`, it compiles to the five instructions `iload …, iconst_1, iadd, i2b, istore …`. The JIT may compensate, but it will never be better than `iinc`/`int`

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use the `for` loop approach, at least put the "work" inside the loop body itself:

```
// create default values
byte loops = 0, sum = 0; 
// loop while there is data and a negative sum 
for(;file.hasNextInt() && sum >= 0; loops++) {
    sum += file.nextInt();
}
```

Personally, though, I'd use `while` approach instead since you're not initializing any variables and using their state to control the `for` loop, and the values being computed are being used outside the `for` loop as well.